# Why does my caroussel gallery do this in responsive? [CSS]

Tags: css, gallery, responsive

I do have a photo Gallery on my site, on laptop it works perfectly, 
but on mobile view, the pictures 1st display well, and after a scroll, becomes very big & blur.

you can see on :

[hidden link]

A working demo can be find also on :
https://fivestar.mikado-themes.com/

I've search for hours but I can not get rid of this bug.
Any help will be much appreciate :*

EDIT : If i activate the original child theme, it works well. So it comes from my custom dev, need to find the one that create this troubles.

EDIT2 : After more investigation, the issue comes from 
http://mv.gr3g.ca/wp-content/themes/fivestar-child/style.css

If i set back to empty style.css the issue disapear. Please fill free to inform me if you see anything wrong in it.

[image]
[image]

Comment: This type of problem is fairly hard to troubleshoot without access to the site. Have you tried deactivating all of your plugins and switching to a default theme so you can determine whether it is a theme or plugin issue? It sounds likely to be either a plugin issue (something that compresses or lazy loads images) or perhaps your images have just been uploaded at such huge sizes they're not loading quickly enough.

Comment: access to the site is in the question ! for plugin, yes i've tryed. no success. For image size, what is strange, is that it first work before scrolling, so i don't think it comes from this. Also, i set exactly the same sizes as in demo, and in demo i see no problem.

Comment: I meant admin access. Not always a lot you can do from the front end. If it wasn't a plugin, it's likely your theme - try swapping that out and if that's the culprit, you can follow up with the developer.

Comment: i'm also in contact with theme developper. i have a start of reply. If i activate the original child theme, it works well. So now i need to make many tests in my customised child theme to see whats wrong

Comment: after some more investigation, issue comes from style.css in child theme, i added url, if you see anything wrong in it, feel free to inform me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, i find the solution !!!

it was this line that makes trouble !

```
.vc_column_container>.vc_column-inner { width:unset !important; }
```